# In MS Access, Have to compare values from two different tables, and find the difference between the values?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a two different tables, Table 1 and table 2.

```
Table 1
-----------
Resource
Start Date
End date
Total Hours

Table 2
------------
Resource 
Reource type
Total Hours
```

Here I have to match the total hours of each table according to the resource,
then have to find the mismatched data and find difference with that values of mismatched data.

Comment: please don't use spaces in table/column names

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Table 1].[Resource], 
       ([Table 1].[Total Hours] - [Table 2].[Total Hours]) As Difference 
FROM [Table 1]
INNER JOIN [Table 2]
  ON [Table 1].[Resource] = [Table 2].[Resource] 
WHERE [Table 1].[Total Hours] <> [Table 2].[Total Hours]
```

If I understand you correctly, this will give you the differences on Total Hours and the Resource it belongs to. The brackets are necessary because of the horrible column and table names.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Resource] is not a unique key in Table1.
So we need some group by clause :

```
SELECT Resource,SUM([Total Hours]) As SumHours1
INTO #SumHours1
FROM [Table 1] 
GROUP BY [Resource];

SELECT Resource,SUM([Total Hours]) As SumHours2
INTO #SumHours2
FROM [Table 2] 
GROUP BY [Resource];

SELECT Resource,SumHours1,SumHours2
FROM #SumHours1 LEFT OUTER JOIN #SumHours2
ON #SumHours1.Resource=#SumHours2.Resource
```